# table width - excel2latex

Tags: tables, width, excel2latex

I converted a table from excel to latex.
My question is, how can I fit the width of the table so that it is nicely align to the margin of the A4 and, depending on the table length, A3?

I tried using

```
tabularx{\linewidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% putting the table here }
```

but the table gets too small even if there is still space on the sides.

There are more tables to include with more data, so I have to find a way to let them be readable and on the other hand not to "waste" 2-3 sheets for every single table.

Would be very grateful for help and suggestions.

Greetings,  Caruso

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, right=30mm, left=30mm}%,top=2cm,bottom=2cm
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9679}{$ \bullet $}

% deutsche Silbentrennung 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Zeichensatzkodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
lore

%\clearpage
%\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize}
%\begin{landscape}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\recalctypearea
%
%
%
%   table then would go here .......
%
%
%
%\end{landscape}
%\clearpage
%
%\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
%\recalctypearea



\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'TeX-Analyse'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|l|c|c|}
\cmidrule{3-8}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{FMEA-Analyse Absauganlagen}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Risikoanalyse}} \\
\cmidrule{3-5}\cmidrule{7-8}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Mittelwerte
aus Expertenbefragung} &       &       & ●     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{empfohlen} \\
\cmidrule{7-8}    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Fehlerquellen und Entdeckung}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1-selten,…,
5-häufig} & 1-unwichtig,…,
5-kritisch & Multiplikation &       & o     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{optional} \\
\cmidrule{7-8}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1-5} & 1-5   & 1-25 möglich & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Komponenten/Fehler}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Fehlerfolge}} & \textbf{Häufigkeit} & \textbf{Wichtigkeit} & \textbf{Ergebnis} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Bemerkung}} & \textbf{Empfohlener Einbau} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ET-1 Kategorie:
Ersatzteilvorhaltung durch Kunden dringend empfohlen, wenn nicht im CM}} \\
    \midrule
          &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Motor } &       &       &       &       & \textbf{Motorüberwachung ET-1 
immer sinnvoll} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Elektromotor fällt aus & Anlagenstillstand & 1.00  & 5.00  & 5.00  &       & o     & x \\
    \midrule
    Laufrad unwuchtig & Vibrationen / später Anlagenstillstand & Nass 4 
sonst 3 & Nass 3
sonst 2,33 & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{Nass 12
sonst 7} &       & Nass ●
Trocken  / ENA o  & x \\
    \midrule
    Laufrad hat falsche Drehrichtung & Volumenstrom unzureichend & 1.50  & Nass 5
sonst 4,33 & Nass 7,5
sonst 6,5 & zu selten, sollte bei Inbetriebnahme geklärt sein & o     & x \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Rohrleitung } &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Rohrleitung verstopft & Absaugleistung sinkt & Nass / Trocken 2,5
ENA 2 & 4.33  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{Nass / Trocken 10,83
ENA 8,67} & kann aus Stromaufnahme abgeleitet werden & Nass / Trocken ●
ENA o &  \\
    \midrule
    Rohgasdichtungen undicht & Volumenstrom sinkt & 1.00  & 3.00  & 3.00  &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Reingasdichtung undicht & Reingas entweicht & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Filterelemente / Demistoren - Trocken, ENA/ÖNA} &       &       &       &       & \textbf{ET-1 Überwachung sinnvoll} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Filter stauben durch, 
Demistoren lassen Partikel durchreißen & Abluft unzureichend gefiltert & 2.50  & 5.00  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{12.50} & Trocken + ENA/ÖNA & Trocken / ENA ● & x \\
    \midrule
    Filter zu / dicht belegt
Demistoren zugesetzt & Absaugleistung sinkt & Trocken 3,5
ENA 3 & 4.67  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{Trocken 16,45
ENA 14} & Trocken + ENA/ÖNA & Trocken / ENA ● & x \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Elektronik - Steuerung} &       &       &       &       & \textbf{ET-1 
Betriebsmeldungen abfragen sinnvoll, 
da schon verhanden, 
allerdings reaktiv} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Taktgeber  defekt & Abreinigung funktioniert unzureichend & 3.00  & 4.50  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{13.50} & Trocken & ●     & x \\
    \midrule
    Hauptschalter defekt & Notaus funktioniert nicht & 1.00  & 3.00  & 3.00  &       &       & x \\
    \midrule
    Frequenzumrichter defekt & Anlage defekt & 2.00  & 5.00  & 10.00 & SPS   & o     & x \\
    \midrule
    RECO SPS defekt & Anlage defekt & 2.00  & 5.00  & 10.00 & SPS   & o     & x \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
        }%
        \caption{Analyse und Einschätzung allgemeiner Bauteile}
  \label{tab:analyseAllg}%
    \end{table}%

\end{landscape}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Anyway, you should not use `\resizebox` with tables. You'll obtain mostly unreadable tables.

Comment: In the meantime I changed the environment to longtable     \setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} 
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}  
    \setlength\LTright{0pt} 
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{15}{c|}}
. The excel2latex table is way too huge, so I need to fit the table to the page width - maybe with resizing the font and try out A4 / A3 paper size. Can someone give me an advice how to adjust the longtable to the condition? I just get 2.5 cells on the widths of the page. How can the table be made of the right size? Any answer is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you update the code in your answer with the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause of your layout problem is, that there's way too much text in some of the boxes. You can start cleaning up the table by moving some of the descriptive text from the header cells into the table caption to provide the necessary explanation.

I used the `sidewaystable` environment (provided by the `rotating` package) and liberally used `\RaggedRight` in `m`-columns to squeeze the columns together. However, this is still not perfect. You should think about shorter texts (preferably only keywords) inside the table and use the table caption for longer descriptions.

For cells containing two pieces of information (e.g. nass/trocken) I used the `minitab` command which is a nested `tabular` environment (a trick I found some time ago here on tex.sx).

In order to make the grey row coloring work I got rid on almost all horizontal and vertical lines, using only a few for emphasis (and a slightly increased `arraystretch` to give more space between `hlines` and cell text).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, right=30mm, left=30mm}%,top=2cm,bottom=2cm
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9679}{$ \bullet $}

% deutsche Silbentrennung 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Zeichensatzkodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating} % provides sidewaystable

\newcommand{\minitab}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}} % nested tabular for 2 short lines in one cell
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} % make table rows a little higher to allow more space between text and hlines
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\RaggedRight}m{2.3cm}>{\RaggedRight}m{2.3cm}|ccc|>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}}m{2.3cm}|cc|}
%
\hline
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\minitab{\textbf{Komponenten/} \\ \textbf{Fehler}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Fehlerfolge}} & \textbf{Häufigkeit} & \textbf{Wichtigkeit} & \textbf{Ergebnis} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Bemerkung}} & \minitab{\textbf{Empfohlener} \\ \textbf{Einbau}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\RaggedRight}m{2.3cm}|}{\textbf{ET-1 Kategorie:
Ersatzteilvorhaltung durch Kunden dringend empfohlen, wenn nicht im CM}} \\
%
\hline
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Motor } &       &       &       &       & \textbf{Motorüberwachung ET-1 
immer sinnvoll} &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    Elektromotor fällt aus & Anlagenstillstand & 1.00  & 5.00  & 5.00  &       & o     & x \\
%    \midrule
    Laufrad unwuchtig & Vibrationen / später Anlagenstillstand & \minitab{Nass 4 \\ 
sonst 3} & \minitab{Nass 3 \\ sonst 2,33} & \minitab{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{Nass 12}\\ \textcolor{red}{sonst 7}} &       & \minitab{Nass ● \\ Trocken  / ENA o } & x \\
%    \midrule
    Laufrad hat falsche Drehrichtung & Volumenstrom unzureichend & 1.50  & \minitab{Nass 5\\sonst 4,33} & \minitab{Nass 7,5 \\ sonst 6,5} & zu selten, sollte bei Inbetriebnahme geklärt sein & o     & x \\
%    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Rohrleitung } &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    Rohrleitung verstopft & Absaugleistung sinkt & \minitab{Nass/Trocken 2,5 \\ ENA 2} & 4.33  & \minitab{\textcolor{red}{Nass/Trocken 10,83} \\ \textcolor{red}{ENA 8,67}} & kann aus Stromaufnahme abgeleitet werden & \minitab{Nass / Trocken ● \\ENA o } &  \\
%    \midrule
    Rohgasdichtungen undicht & Volumenstrom sinkt & 1.00  & 3.00  & 3.00  &       &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    Reingasdichtung undicht & Reingas entweicht & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  &       &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Filterelemente/ Demistoren - Trocken, ENA/ÖNA} &       &       &       &       & \textbf{ET-1 Überwachung sinnvoll} &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    Filter stauben durch, 
Demistoren lassen Partikel durchreißen & Abluft unzureichend gefiltert & 2.50  & 5.00  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{12.50} & Trocken + ENA/ÖNA & Trocken / ENA ● & x \\
%    \midrule
    Filter zu / dicht belegt
Demistoren zugesetzt & Absaugleistung sinkt & \minitab{Trocken 3,5 \\ ENA 3} & 4.67  & \minitab{\textcolor{red}{Trocken 16,45} \\ \textcolor{red}{ENA 14}} & Trocken + ENA/ÖNA & Trocken / ENA ● & x \\
%    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Elektronik - Steuerung} &       &       &       &       & \textbf{ET-1 Betriebsmeldungen abfragen sinnvoll, da schon verhanden, 
allerdings reaktiv} &       &  \\
%    \midrule
    Taktgeber  defekt & Abreinigung funktioniert unzureichend & 3.00  & 4.50  & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{13.50} & Trocken & ●     & x \\
%    \midrule
    Hauptschalter defekt & Notaus funktioniert nicht & 1.00  & 3.00  & 3.00  &       &       & x \\
%    \midrule
    Frequenzumrichter defekt & Anlage defekt & 2.00  & 5.00  & 10.00 & SPS   & o     & x \\
%    \midrule
    RECO SPS defekt & Anlage defekt & 2.00  & 5.00  & 10.00 & SPS   & o     & x \\
%    \bottomrule
\hline
    \end{tabular}%
%        }%
        \caption[FMEA-Analyse von Absauganlagen und Einschätzung allgemeiner Bauteile]{FMEA-Analyse von Absauganlagen und Einschätzung allgemeiner Bauteile\\ Mittelwerte aus der Expertenbefragung: Häufigkeit 1-selten\dots 5-häufig, Wichtigkeit: 1-unwichtig\dots 5-kritisch, \\ Ergebnis: Multiplikationsfaktor 1-25 möglich, Empfehlung: ● empfohlen/o nicht empfohlen}
  \label{tab:analyseAllg}%

\end{sidewaystable}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: cheers, thank you, I try to incorporate that into my tex :)

Answer (score 0):

Even setting font to 
    \small 
and trying to adjust longtable width to 
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{6}{c|}} gives me way too broad table. Is there a way to fit the table to the provided paper (A3/A4) page width?
I've got here something terribly wrong...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, right=30mm, left=30mm}%,top=2cm,bottom=2cm
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9679}{$ \bullet $}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} 
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            
\setlength\LTright{0pt}  

\begin{document}
ipsum

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\recalctypearea
\small
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{6}{c|}}


\toprule
\rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \textbf{Motor } &       &       &       &       & \textbf{Stromaufnahme immer sinnvoll} \\
\midrule
Elektromotor fällt aus & über SPS Betriebsmeldung
Motorsensorik > Übertemperatur
Überwachung Lager  > Akustik
Stromaufnahme & Mit CM überwachen & SPS Betriebsmeldung
spezieller Motorsensor (ABB)  Lager 
/ Motor-Temperatur
Akustiksensor erkennt Lagerschäden
Stromaufnahme steigt schlagartig & B, M  &  \\
\midrule
Laufrad unwuchtig & Schwingungssensor
Akustiksensor nimmt ebenso Schwingungen auf & Mit CM überwachen &     Schwingungen erhöhen sich 
/ erreichen Grenzwert & B     & dauerhafte Installation von     Schwingungssensoren bei Naßabscheidern \\
\midrule
Laufrad hat falsche Drehrichtung & Filterwiderstand (Differenzdruck)
Stromaufnahme
Volumenstromsensorik (dynam. Druck)
Drehrichtungssensorik & indirekt überwachen (Stromaufnahme) & Widerstände     sinken
Stromaufnahme sinkt
Volumenstrom sinkt
Drehrichtung falsch & M     & passiert wenn Kunde etwa Einspeisung ändert,
sollte ansonsten durch Inbetriebnahme geklärt sein \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\end{landscape}
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\normalsize
ipsum
\end{document}
```